# Finding conditions for $\mathbb Z[i][X,Y]/(Y^2 - aX)$, $a \in \mathbb Z[i]$ to be regular

Tags: commutative-algebra

> I am trying to find the dimension and the necessary and sufficient conditions under which $A[X,Y]/(Y^2 - aX)$ is regular, that is, the localizations of $A[X,Y]/(Y^2 - aX)$ at all maximal ideals are regular, where $A$ are the Gaussian integers and $a \in A$. Any hints?

I can't even see what the max ideals are. Thanks.

Comment: Dimension is two. $a=0$ is out of question since then $Y$ belongs to the maximal ideal and $Y^2$ to its square, so the factor ring is not regular.

Comment: @user26857 why is the dimension two?

Comment: Since $A[X,Y]$ is an integral domain, $\dim A[X,Y]=3$ and we factor this by a non-zero element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $M$ be a maximal ideal of $A[X,Y]/(Y^2-aX)$. Then $M=\mathfrak m/(Y^2-aX)$, where $\mathfrak m$ is a maximal ideal in $A[X,Y]$ containing $Y^2-aX$. We have $$\left(\dfrac{A[X,Y]}{(Y^2-aX)}\right)_M=\dfrac{A[X,Y]_{\mathfrak m}}{(Y^2-aX)}.$$
(I) If $a=0$, then $Y\in \mathfrak m$, so $Y^2\in \mathfrak m^2$, hence $A[X,Y]_{\mathfrak m}/(Y^2)$ isn't regular.

(II) If $a\ne 0$ and there is $p\in A$ irreducible such that $p\mid a$, then consider $\mathfrak m=(p,X,Y)$, and note that $p\in \mathfrak m-\mathfrak m^2$. If $A[X,Y]_{\mathfrak m}/(Y^2-aX)$ is regular, then its factor ring by the ideal $(p)$ is also regular, that is, $(A/pA)[X,Y]_{\mathfrak m}/(Y^2-\bar aX)$ is regular. But $\bar a=\bar 0$ in $A/pA$ and we are in case (I).

(III) Suppose $a\ne0$ and there is no irreducible $p\in A$ such that $p\mid a$, that is, $a$ is invertible. In this case $A[X,Y]/(Y^2-aX)\simeq A[Y]$ is regular.

Conclusion: $A[X,Y]/(Y^2-aX)$ is regular if and only if $a$ is invertible.

**Remark.** The proof works for $A$ a PID.